# Stieltjes integral and conditional expectation

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation

The following statement shows up in the proof of the Strengthened Fefferman Inequality in Protter's *Stochastic Integration and Differential Equations*.

> Let $f$ be a random variable in $\mathcal{F}_\infty$ and $A_t$ be an increasing process with $A_0=0$ such that
> \begin{align*}
> E\left[\int_0^\infty |f| dA_t\right]<\infty
> \end{align*}
> Then we have the following:
> \begin{align*}
> E[fA_\infty] = E\left[\int_0^\infty f\ dA_t\right]= E\left[\int_0^\infty E[f|\mathcal{F}_t]\ dA_t\right]
> \end{align*}

However, the second identity is not obvious. The conditional expectation depends on $t$, so in this case we cannot exchange the conditional expectation and the integral to conclude the result. My question is how can we conclude the second identity?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

One possible proof I can think of is applying Integration by part formula:

Let $M_t=E[f|\mathcal{F}_t]$. It is sufficient to prove the result for bounded $f$, then we can apply dominated convergence theorem for general $f$. $M_t$ is then bounded. Therefore, since $A_0=0$
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty M_{s^-}dA_s = M_\infty A_\infty-\int_0^\infty A_{s^-}dM_s-[M,A]_\infty
\end{align*}
Since $M$ is a martingale and $A$ is locally bounded, $\int_0^t A_{s^-}dM_s$ is a local martingale. Note from the above formula, we can see $E[\sup_{[0,\infty]}|\int_0^t A_{s^-}dM_s|]<\infty$. This implies this local martingale is a true martingale.

Next since $A$ is finite variation, $[M,A]_\infty=\sum \Delta M\Delta A$. Therefore, we have
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty M_{s}dA_s = M_\infty A_\infty-\int_0^\infty A_{s^-}dM_s
\end{align*}
Take expectation on both sides, we have
\begin{align*}
E\left[\int_0^\infty E[f|\mathcal{F}_s]dA_s\right]=E\left[\int_0^\infty M_{s}dA_s\right]=E[M_\infty A_\infty]=E[E[f|\mathcal{F}_\infty] A_\infty]=E[fA_\infty]
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Do we know that $A_t$ is adapted? If we can approximate the integral by
$\sum_{i=0}^{i=n} f(w)(A_{t_{i+1}}(w)-A_{t_{i}}(w))$ and if we know $A$ is adapted, then

$E[\sum_{i=0}^{i=n} f(w)(A_{t_{i+1}}(w)-A_{t_{i}}(w))]\\
=E[\sum_{i=0}^{i=n} E[f(w)|F_{t_i}](A_{t_{i+1}}(w)-A_{t_{i}}(w))]\\$.

Then we should be able to show that the right handside converges to $E[\int_{0}^{\infty}E[f|F_{t}]dA_{t}]$

Comment: Thanks for answering!. I think the right side will converge to $E[\int_0^\infty E[f|F_{t-}]dA_t]$. The only problem left is to prove $E[f|F_{t}]$ has continuous sample path (however, I thought about this problem before and have no clue).

Comment: For $F_n$ increasing, we know $E[f|F_n]$ converges in L1 and a.s. to $E[f|\cup F_n]$. while for  $F_n$ decreasing, we know $E[f|F_n]$ converges in L1 and a.s. to $E[f|\cap F_n]$. Does that help?